# C# Double.Parse вопрос

Tags: .net

Есть строка "1.260", с помощью Double.Parse("1.260") получается число double 1.26.

Как сделать так, чтобы после парсинга 0 на конце остался, и мы получили переменную double a = 1.260?

Comment: А чем, по-вашему, число 1.260 отличается от числа 1.26? [Подсказка](http://ideone.com/7idw7O).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Значение 1.260 хранится в памяти как

```
00111111 11110100 00101000 11110101
11000010 10001111 01011100 00101001
```

`0` на конце существует только в десятичном строковом представлении числа. Собственно, его вы и видите в отладчике. Его же вы видите при выводе, например, на консоль:

```
Console.WriteLine(1.26); // 1.26
```

если вам нужно получить ровно 3 символа после точки в строковом представлении - вы должны явно указать это при преобразовании числа обратно в строку:

```
string stringRepresentation = 1.26.ToString("0.000"); //  1.26 ->  "1.260"
Console.WriteLine(stringRepresentation);
```

или

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000}", 1.26);  // 1.260
```

подробно особенности форматирования чисел расписаны в MSDN, в статье  [Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).